# Using Google Authenticator for SSH sessions

Tags: authentication, ssh, one-time-password

So I have an SSH tunnel which I use with dynamic port forwarding to the alternate http port on the client. For initializing this connection, I'd like to implement an additional verification step, preferably phone / SMS verification and the Google authenticator (https://developers.google.com/identity/
) should be the best solution.

How should I start implementing a standalone module that can be used in the authenticator app without having to expose google credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Authenticator implements standard protocols such as [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) (and maybe [HOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm)), they are not Google-specific nor depend on Google's servers, so using their PAM module isn't related to your Google account and doesn't need an online connection.

If you're like me and don't trust Google you can use an independent [PAM module](http://www.nongnu.org/oath-toolkit/) and an independent authenticator app implementing either the HOTP or TOTP protocol (search your phone's App Store).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to get this work along with public key auth? It seems, it lets me in without the code if I have a key stored.